# There some thing not right going with Cloneable interface

Tags: java

```
public class Tool extends Item {
    @Override
    public Item clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

clone() method is giving me an error:

> Cannot directly invoke the abstract method clone() for the type Item

Item class is a abstract class which implements Cloneable interface.

Comment: Is `Item` an abstract class? If so, you can’t override the method, then try to call the superclass’ implementation inside of it because an implementation does not exist.

Comment: It does not give me any error. Did you try this? Anyway you have to cast return type to `Item` because it returns type of `Object`

Comment: Can you please elaborate what can be done to correct it

Comment: I too don't see any issue, you may need to specify which line gives you error. Look into the my piece of code which is working fine.

Comment: It is commonly understood that `Cloneable` interface in Java is broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CloneTest {

    static abstract class Item implements Cloneable {
        private boolean stackable;

        protected String name;

        public Item() {
            this.name = new String("Air");
            this.stackable = true;
        }

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.stackable = true;
        }

        public Item(String name, boolean stackable) {
            this.name = name;
            this.stackable = stackable;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String n) {
            this.name = n;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
            Item r = (Item) rhs;

            return (this.name).equals(r.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return this.name.hashCode();
        }

        public boolean isStackable() {
            return this.stackable;
        }

        public abstract void read(Scanner s);

        @Override
        public Item clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
           Object obj = super.clone();
           // Add some custom logic here... like initializing few members
           return (Item) obj;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return (" " + this.name);
        }
    }

    public static class Tool extends Item {

        @Override
        public Item clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return super.clone();
        }

        @Override
        public void read(Scanner s) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException 
{
        Tool tool1 = new Tool();
        System.out.println(tool1);
        Object tool2 = tool1.clone();
        System.out.println(tool2);
        System.out.println(tool1 == tool2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine, but if I do this then I won't be able to call clone() method using Item class object. Can you please help me with some alternative

Comment: We call `super.clone()` when we want to handover either fully or a portion of cloning process to super class. But in you case you have declared `clone` method abstract and calling abstract/non-implemented method in child class. So solution is either you remove abstract `clone` method from super class so that API can invoke 'java.lang.Object.clone()' method or implement `clone` method. Possibly what I understand is, if you have custom cloning logic in super class `Item` then implement `clone` method. I updated code again.